# TVirtualStringTree - How to use my own hint window class for VT columns?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I want to use a custom Hint window class for my entire application. 
I use the `Application.OnShowHint`, analyze the `THintInfo`, and return my own `TMyHintWindow` in the `HintInfo.HintWindowClass`. This works well for all controls but I have a strange problem only with `TVirtualStringTree` *Columns* hint.

VT uses it's own hint window and own structure for the `HintInfo.HintData`. I study the code, and know it uses the `VTHintData`. so far so good. problem is that when I return my own hint window class (derived from `THintWindow`) it shows the hint window only for a split second and disappears!

There is no problem with hints returned for tree Nodes. they use the same method/structure (`VTHintData`).

Here is a very simple MCVE:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, VirtualTrees, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    
  private
  public
    procedure ApplicationShowHint(var HintStr: string; var CanShow: Boolean;
      var HintInfo: THintInfo);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TMyHintWindow = class(THintWindow)
  public
    { nothing special here for now }
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VirtualStringTree1.Hint := 'VT main hint';
  VirtualStringTree1.ShowHint := True;

  Memo1.Hint := 'Memo hint';
  Memo1.ShowHint := True;

  Application.OnShowHint := ApplicationShowHint;
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationShowHint(var HintStr: string; var CanShow: Boolean;
  var HintInfo: THintInfo);
var
  VTHintData: TVTHintData;
begin
  { VT uses it's own hint window class }
  if HintInfo.HintWindowClass = TVirtualTreeHintWindow then
  begin
    { VT passes columns and nodes hints information in HintInfo.HintData }
    if HintInfo.HintData <> nil then
    begin
      VTHintData := PVTHintData(HintInfo.HintData)^;
      if VTHintData.Node <> nil then { node hint }
      begin
        { handle this case with DoGetNodeHint/DoGetNodeToolTip ... it works fine }
      end
      else
      begin { column hint }
        HintStr := VTHintData.DefaultHint; { got it! }
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add(HintStr); { prove I got the right hint }

  HintInfo.HintColor := clAqua;

  { use my own hint window class
    the hint from the VT columns is shown for a split second and hides! }
  HintInfo.HintWindowClass := TMyHintWindow;
end;

end.
```

Form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 399
  Top = 256
  Width = 720
  Height = 211
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 409
    Height = 153
    Header.AutoSizeIndex = 0
    Header.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Header.Font.Color = clWindowText
    Header.Font.Height = -11
    Header.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
    Header.Font.Style = []
    Header.Options = [hoColumnResize, hoDrag, hoShowHint, hoShowSortGlyphs, hoVisible]
    HintAnimation = hatNone
    HintMode = hmTooltip
    TabOrder = 0
    Columns = <
      item
        Position = 0
        Width = 150
        WideText = 'column 0'
        WideHint = 'VT column 0 hint'
      end
      item
        Position = 1
        Width = 150
        WideText = 'column 1'
        WideHint = 'VT column 1 hint'
      end>
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 424
    Top = 8
    Width = 273
    Height = 153
    ScrollBars = ssVertical
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

I have debugged this for hours. I see nothing special. 
Why is this happening? who/what closes the hint window right away?
Thanks.

I'm using VT version 5.3.0

---

In the `TBaseVirtualTree.CMHintShowPause()` it is stated:

> A little workaround is needed here to make the application class
>   using the correct hint window class.    Once the application gets
>   ShowHint set to true (which is the case when we want to show hints in
>   the tree) then    an internal hint window will be created which is not
>   our own class (because we don't set an application wide    hint window
>   class but only one for the tree). **Unfortunately, this default hint**
>   **window class will prevent    hints for the non-client area to show up**
>   **(e.g. for the header)** by calling CancelHint whenever certain messages 
>   arrive. By setting the hint show pause to 0 if our hint class was not
>   used recently we make sure    that the hint timer (in Forms.pas) is
>   not used and our class is created immediately.

I'm not really sure how to handle this. I think I'll drop the whole idea of using my won hint class for the header columns.

Comment: That `hmTooltip` hint mode looks suspicious. Tooltips are hints that are about to be displayed instantly.

Comment: @Victoria, Thanks. as I understand it, `hmTooltip` activates tool tips for the nodes only. not columns. I have tried every other `HintMode`. BTW, Can you reproduce?

Comment: @zig: which VirtualTree version do you have?

Comment: @deblocker.version 5.3.0

Comment: @zig: i'm using an older version, but just by reading quickly the source i found this comment `remove hint if any in case the tree loses the focus`. Did you investigated that case?